# Mongodb db.get('usercollection') not working corretly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, monk

Issue is that db is not working properly

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest1');

var routes = require('./routes');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var app = express.createServer();
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.use(function(req,res,next){
  req.db = db;
  next();
});
```

routes/index.js

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('usercollection');
  collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
    res.render('userlist', {
      "userlist" : docs
    });
  });
};
```

When I run userlist I get an error on line db.get('usercollection'). When I log req.db it is undefined.
How to resolve it?

Comment: Can you show the error you are getting. `var db=req.db` looks wrong, I suspect you have not opened a connection to your db

Comment: yes u r right....error is
Error: failed to locate view "error"

Comment: The db you want to reference is unlikely to be `req.db` ... check to see if db is defined

Comment: yes in app.js

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});

Comment: can you post the full app.js and and the full index.js ... makes no sense so far

Comment: I udpate the question

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use your db module in the index.js file

```
module.exports = (function() {
'use strict';
var apiRoutes = express.Router();

var Server = mongo.Server;
var Db = mongo.Db;
var BSON = mongo.BSONPure;

function connexionDataBase(callback){

var server = new Server('your db URL', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true}); 
db = new Db('you Db', server);
db.open(function(err, db) {

    if(!err) {

        console.log("Connected to 'you Db' database");

        callback(err,db);

    }
    else{

        console.log("not Connected to 'you Db' database");
        callback(err,db);

    }
});

})();
```

and in your app.js your can redirect the app routes to index.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var index = require('./index');
var app = express();
app.use('/index',index);
```